# split timestamp by hour

Tags: python

I have a list of timestamps in ISO format

`[u"2000-01-01T00:00:00+00:00",  u"2000-01-01T00:00:00+00:00",  ...  ]`

I'm trying to split each string by the hour. However, using `"string".strp(":")` obviously won't work, because of a `too many values to unpack` error (due to several :'s) and `"string".strp(":%S")` gives a value error of `more than one value to unpack`. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

`iso8601` is a wonderful, open source python module to parse ISO datetime strings http://code.google.com/p/pyiso8601/

It turns it into python's native `datetime` type which should be easier to work with.

Answer (score 2):

You have two choices. You can either use [`datetime.datetime.strptime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to give you `datetime` objects, and then just do `dt.hour`, which you may want to do anyways, depending on what you're doing with these.

Or, alternatively, if you want to just use string processing as you are, you can use `str.split` as you've shown, but with its optional second argument, which is the maximum number of times to split, so `s.split(":", 1)`. Or similarly, `str.partition`, which basically would do the same as that but not raise an error for a thing without a ":". With both of these, you'd need to then strip off the things at the beginning of the time using slicing.

Comment: I would like to try str.partition without raising the 2nd value error; how would you slicing to solve this? (I'm not sure I follow)

Comment: `value, _, _ = u"2000-01-01T00:00:00+00:00".partition(":")`   
`hour = value[-2:]`

Comment: Thanks!
Another point: if I wanted to use datetime.datetime.strptime, what is the correct format? "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+...." 
What's the last part for time zone (cannot find it)?